# Нужна помощь в работе с Аффинной системой подстановок Цезаря на С#

Tags: c#

Задали лабу, состоящую из 4 шифров, на расшифровке 2-ого я немного запутался. Вот именно с зашифровкой всё легко, а с расшифровкой вообще никак.
Суть:
[image: Обьяснние]
Не могу понять, как вывести inv[K] из нижней формулы. В сети написано, что решается алгоритмом Евклида. Могу решить, конечно, подбором, но это долго и глупо. Помогите с реализацией функции, выводящей inv[K] из уравнения. Остальные данные у меня есть.
Спасибо!

Comment: Покажите ваш нерабочий код.

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22225058/12888024)